# How to implement median filter with a kernel in MATLAB to smooth an image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, median, noise-reduction

I don't know how to implement a median filter with a sliding window (kernel) in MATLAB. I need to know how the implementation looks like so I can try to implement a BSE algorithm (block smart erase), which is very similar to the median filter. I need that to erase some black and white pixels. I know that there's the medfilt2() function but I need to know how it is implemented.

The BSE algorithm works like this:

The BSE algorithm is based on median technology and takes the place of the extreme value (black or white) pixel by the median value of their surrounding pixels.

1) For an NxN window centered at the test pixel, where N would normally be and larger value should be suggested.

2) If f(i,j) = 0 or f(i,j) = 255, f(i,j) is an absolute extreme value pixel that must be estimated; go to step 3. Otherwise, the value of f(i,j) is not altered; go to step 4.

3) When an extreme value pixel is detected, its gray level is substituted by the median value of the window.

4) The procedure is repeated for the next window.

What I understood was that I need to implement the median filter with a condition to check if the current pixel value is 0 or 255. If it is, I change that value for the median value of its neighbourhood pixels.

I dont know if I was clear enough but I need some help with that:).

Current BSE algorithm:

```
function [outimg] = medianfilt(img,sz)
green  = img(:,:,2);
[rows,cols] = size(green);    % get size of grayscale image
pad = sz-1; % padding to be added
nimg = zeros(rows+pad,cols+pad); % padded image
nimg(pad/2+1:rows+pad/2, pad/2+1:cols+pad/2) = green;
outimg = zeros(rows,cols);  % output / median filtered image
for x = pad/2 + 1 : cols + pad/2  % loop over columns
    for y = pad/2 + 1 : rows + pad/2   % loop over rows
        if nimg(y,x) == 0 || nimg(y,x) == 255
            win = nimg(y-pad/2:y+pad/2, x-pad/2:x+pad/2);  % get mxm window
            outimg(y-pad/2,x-pad/2) = median(win(:));      % find median
        else
            outimg(y-pad/2,x-pad/2) = nimg(y,x);
        end
        win = nimg(y-pad/2:y+pad/2, x-pad/2:x+pad/2);  % get mxm window
        outimg(y-pad/2,x-pad/2) = median(win(:));      % find median
    end
end
imshow(outimg);
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can implement median filter as below:

```
function [outimg] = medianfilt(img,sz)
    [rows,cols] = size(img);    % get size of grayscale image
    pad = sz-1; % padding to be added
    nimg = zeros(rows+pad,cols+pad); % padded image
    nimg(pad/2+1:rows+pad/2, pad/2+1:cols+pad/2) = img;
    outimg = zeros(rows,cols);  % output / median filtered image
    for x = pad/2 + 1 : cols + pad/2  % loop over columns
        for y = pad/2 + 1 : rows + pad/2   % loop over rows 
            win = nimg(y-pad/2:y+pad/2, x-pad/2:x+pad/2);  % get mxm window
            outimg(y-pad/2,x-pad/2) = median(win(:));      % find median
        end
    end
end
```

you can check for BSE as below:

```
if nimg(y,x) == 0 || nimg(y,x) == 255
    win = nimg(y-pad/2:y+pad/2, x-pad/2:x+pad/2);  % get mxm window
    outimg(y-pad/2,x-pad/2) = median(win(:));      % find median
else
    outimg(y-pad/2,x-pad/2) = nimg(y,x);
end
```

Comment: If you switch the loops over `y` and `x`, you'll get a significant speed improvement. MATLAB stores arrays column-wise, and it is always fastest to iterate over an array in storage order (has to do with data locality and cache misses).

Comment: Thanks, @user8190419!!

If I want to do that condition from BSE algorithm, all I need to do is a if condition after getting the mxm window? Or how would it be?

Comment: What the 'sz' stands for?

Comment: it is size of the window i.e. 3x3 or 5x5 or 7x7 .... you should call it as `medianfilt( imread(path), 3)`

Comment: It shows an error: "Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch." Showing that the error is in that line:  nimg(pad/2+1:rows+pad/2, pad/2+1:cols+pad/2) = img;

Comment: check if you are using rgb image with it because above code is for grayscale image

Comment: pass one component of rgb image like `medianfilt( rgb(:,:,1), 3)`

Comment: I'm doing something wrong but I can't figure out what it is. I'm trying to follow an article implementation which uses OCF (open-close filter) and COF(close-open filter) followed by BSE algorithm in both OCF and COF resultant images to reduce the noise. Turns out that when I apply the BSE you gave me, my image turns out to be only black and white...

Comment: first check results of BSE and OCF/COF separately, if both gives correct result then integrate them.

Comment: yea and now out of a sudden, the function is not working anymore. I keep getting this error: "Undefined function or variable 'medianfilt'."

Comment: you should place the medianfilt.m file in the same directory or add the folder to the path

Comment: yea it is in the same directory and even thou is not working anymore :(

Comment: what error you are getting? your filename should be medianfilt.m and should be in same directory. Also you should pass a graysacle image to the function.

Comment: How could I get in chat with you? I guess I'm not being clear enough.

Comment: I'm processing an image (grayscale) doing the OCF and COF sequence for, later, use the BSE code you gave me. I have both OCF and COF results and I want to process both (each per turn) with BSE. But all I get, now, is a black and white image, and I'm passing the grayscale image.

Comment: I edited my question with the current code I have at the moment.

Comment: I made it! I forgot to normalize the image! Now the BSE algorithm is working well! THanks so much for your attention and help! You're a mvp!

Answer (score 1):

As you noted, MATLAB has `medfilt2`. You can use this function to build your filter:

```
img = imread(...);
med = medfilt2(img);
mask = img==0 | img==255;
img(mask) = med(mask);
```

What the code above does is

1. compute the median filtered image `med`,
2. identify the pixels that need to be replaced (pixels with a value of 0 or 255), leading to a logical array `mask` that can be used for indexing, and finally
3. replace the given pixels in the input image with the corresponding pixels from the median-filtered image.